# Confusion in Barrier Tunelling formula for physics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation

is the formula T = e^-2(alpha)a

where alpha = ((2m(V-E))^1/2)/h

or is it T = 16(E/V)[ 1-E/V]e^-2[(alpha)(a)]?

my book seems to have the second formula but Ive seen online solutions using the first formula

Comment: Please use [Mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on this site.  It is the site standard for mathematics.

Answer (score 0):

The general solution for the tunneling probability is: $$ T = \frac{|F|^{2}}{|A|^{2}} $$
Where *F* is the amplitude of the transmitted complex wave and *A* is the amplitude of the complex wave incident on the potential barrier. The second equation you shared seems to be an approximation used in the case of a rectangular potential barrier where $ E < V_0 $ (http://tuttle.merc.iastate.edu/ee439/topics/tunneling.pdf). The exact expression for *T* is a bit more complicated. I would assume the first equation you mentioned would be used in an attempt to further simplify the solution, neglecting the prefactor and highlighting the exponential decay $e^{-2{\alpha}a}$.